# Change kernel in grub

Tags: debian, kernel, grub2, virtual-machine

I am trying to change to the installed OpenVZ kernel in my fresh install of Debian 8.8.

This is list of my installed kernels:
[image]

So I edited my /etc/default/grub like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=2
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and then I executed `grub-update` however after reboot I am still with my original kernel so I cannot use OpenVZ. The only problem I could think of if that my CPU is Skylake so maybe that kernel is not compatible? Is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible to run this OpenVZ kernel entering the Advanced options in GRUB ? Do you want to run this kernel as default option ?

Comment: @mrc02_kr It is a remote server I do not have access to boot menu or bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `update-initramfs` to update the existing kernel to a new one. You can do that like this:

```
update-initramfs -c -k 2.6.32-openvz-042stab123.9-amd64
```

If the kernel initramfs already exists, move your old kernels into a different directory and run `update-grub`

Comment: For some reason it says: https://pastebin.com/3SjnXJNX

Comment: @Welite Your syntax is wrong, use the updated answer.. I put your kernel name in it.

Comment: Cannot create version 2.6.32-openvz-042stab123.9-amd64: already exists

Comment: Try `update-initramfs -u`

Comment: No error just this output: update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64

Comment: Move all your old kernels to a folder called old-kernels in your `/boot` directory, then run `update-initramfs -u`

Comment: What do you mean by kernel ? The config files ? Here is how my /boot looks like: https://i.gyazo.com/8aa28a894bda34d8a224323c330017b1.png

Comment: Move all the files that have 3.16.0-4-amd64 to another folder in /boot and then run `update-grub` because the kernel initramfs is already there, you don't need to run `update-initramfs`

Comment: Ok that worked: https://pastebin.com/PG6dP8Lx, so now I just set in /etc/default/grub the index of the right kernel or I dont have to do anything and just reboot now ?

Comment: Its fixed. Just reboot